# how to deploy Angular + Springboot project using nginx on azure remote desktop. i am getting this cors errors while accesing the remote site

Tags: angular, spring-boot, azure, nginx, deployment

i am new to deployment. i used Azure remote server for my project deployment. as you aware that angular uses localhost:4200 and springboot uses localhost:8080. when i run the project on remote server itself then it is working fine. but when i running / accesing it remotely through remote server ip then i can only able to access the front end part. and when i check the console they are showing cors errors.

for the cors errors i had already addded code in backend. so there is no issue as such. but when i try to access it remotely then it gives this error.

1 st Error)
main.7dc5cf0db6092584.js:1 ERROR
Mk {headers: Ws, status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: 'http://localhost:8080/projects', ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: 'error', …}
headers: Ws {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/projects: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://localhost:8080/projects"
[[Prototype]]: mb

2 nd Error)
"/#/main/uikit/crudrules:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/escrule' from origin 'http://70.91.52.87' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`."

3rd Error)
polyfills.8078d748ada0b716.js:1 GET http://localhost:8080/projects net::ERR_FAILED

for your information i am giving my nginx config file code.

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
     upstream springboot
    {
        server localhost:8080  max_conns=10;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
    #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   "C:/project related/NewAuditUi/dist/california-ng";
            try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        }
    location /api {
                 proxy_pass    http://springboot;
          proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For 
$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        } 
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }   
    }
}
```

> i welcome ur all suggestions. if need more information then dont hesitate to ask. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your angular application, try setting the options. To call the  HTTP request, use these options.

```
const options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    Authorization: 'Basic ',// your authorization method
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':
      'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  })
};

getPerson(name: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .get<any>(baseUrl + '/persons/' + name, options)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input...and i had tried this code but still not able to access the backend and ERROR Something bad happened; please try again later. this error shown in browser console.